How to reverse a number (reverse the digits) using Java Stream API?
How to reverse a number using Java Stream API?
Reverse meaning: reversing digits. For example, if there is a variable:
int num = 12734;

I want to have output as:
output = 43721;


if you meant reverse the digit orders, what should result with for example 1000?

if really needing the Stream API, check the reduce() method of Stream

Why reverse the digits of a number using a Java Stream?  Yes, there are streams ... but you don't need to use them for everything.

@StephenC  I want to do this using Streams. I am aware we can achieve reversing digits using StringBuilder but still i want to explore how it can be done using Java Stream.

@OldDogProgrammer Yes when i say reversing the number i meant reversing digits, int num = 12734;
i want to have output as,
output = 43721;

"Yes when i say reversing the number i meant reversing digits, int num = 12734; i want to have output as, output = 43721"  But as asked by @user85421 what about numbers with trailing 0's (e.g  10000)?  As an int that would be 1 when reversed/

BTW, some ints of 10 digits will overflow when reversed and will not produce the desired results.  So using Strings is probably the best solution regardless of whether streams are used or not.

@SanjayNaik you would do best to edit your question and resolve the unanswered questions in the comments.  Otherwise, even if it is reopened it will likely get closed again and possibly deleted.

if a String is acceptable: Integer.toString(1234).codePoints().mapToObj(Character::toString).reduce((a,b) -> b+a).orElseThrow()
